# Define hyphenation rules in a separate file

Tags: hyphenation

I always try to organize my document through the use of dedicated files. I was wondering if there is a way to define the hyphenation rules that are normally part of the preamble in a separate file?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: You can alway put them in a dedicated `.tex` file then `\input{...}` them in the preamble

Comment: @Luis Turcio Thank you very much for this solution! I didn't know that you can use \input{...} in the preamble. So far i only used it in the document for my text files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Luis Turcio provided the following answer (see comment below the question):

You can alway put them in a dedicated .tex file then \input{...} them in the preamble.